# how to time an oracle select query

Tags: oracle, plsql

what is the best way to find out how much time an oracle select statement takes. I have the following query for which I want to find out the time, however, since this query brings four thousand records and it takes time to display those 4 thousand records on the screen, the elapsed time stated might not be correct.

Is there a way I can wrap this into a cursor and then run it from sql plus so that I get the correct time it takes to execute this?

```
SELECT a.code, NVL(a.org, ' '), NVL(a.office_number, ' '), SUBSTR(a.code, 0, 2) 
FROM PARTICIPANT a WHERE a.type_code = 'PRIME';
```

Comment: How are you currently getting the "elapsed time stated"?

Comment: I am just running it on sqlplus by doing `set timing on` before I run the query.  This paints the records on the screen and then gives me an elapsed time.  I think the painting of records on the screen is also being taken as elapsed time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of.

I normally do this sort of thing by running it into a table with `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT....`, which means I often litter my schema with many tables named `MIKE_TEMP_1`.

Other option is in SQL*Plus to use `SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY` which should run all the query but suppress the printing of the results.

Comment: Be aware that doing a CREATE TABLE AS SELECT will somewhat regularly generate a query plan different than the plan of the underlying SELECT statement.  So that is not always a particularly good test.  +1 for the SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY option though.

Comment: yup. autotrace traceonly wins

Comment: @justin I do data warehousing work so the CTAS plan is generally what I want anyway. But I do accept your point.

Comment: The CTAS would have the additional cost/time of the physical writes. I'd go for the TRACEONLY option.

Answer (score 8):

In SQL*Plus you can also use the simple TIMING option:

```
SQL> SET TIMING ON
SQL> SELECT bla FROM bla...
...
Elapsed: 00:00:00:01
SQL> SELECT bar FROM foo...
...
Elapsed: 00:00:23:41
SQL> SET TIMING OFF
```

This will report timing information for each statement individually.

Another option is to set up individual timers:

```
SQL> TIMING START mytimer
SQL> ... run all my scripts ...
SQL> TIMING STOP
timinig for: mytimer
Elapsed: 00:00:08.32
```

You can even nest these individual timers - the `TIMING STOP` pops the most recent timer off a stack.

Comment: oops, sorry I didn't see your comment that you're already doing this. Oh well, this answer might be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Options that spring to mind:

a) use an outer select, which may not be entirely accurate if the optimizer mangles it but can give a good idea:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from (
    SELECT a.code, NVL(a.org, ' '), NVL(a.office_number, ' '), SUBSTR(a.code, 0, 2) 
    FROM PARTICIPANT a WHERE a.type_code = 'PRIME'
);
```

b) put it in a script, run it from the command line and redirect the output to a file.

c) turn spool on and termout off (not sure about that one).

d) `set autotrace traceonly` (which @MikeyByCrikey beat me to).

Comment: Yes, (c) works.  Of course it takes some finite time for SQL Plus to spool to a file, but it is nothing like as significant as output to the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can go to V$SQL where you have the following columns :

```
APPLICATION_WAIT_TIME
CONCURRENCY_WAIT_TIME
CLUSTER_WAIT_TIME
USER_IO_WAIT_TIME
PLSQL_EXEC_TIME
CPU_TIME
ELAPSED_TIME
```

but they are an aggregate for all executions of that SQL. You can do a before/after snapshot and work out the difference if no-one else is running the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just do not display query results

```
SET TERMOUT OFF
```